# Weird behavior in Chrome with HTML select

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-select

I have a CSS menu pretty simple, that's show an list UL on hover. From a time ago, in Chrome, when I select an option that is on the same position as the menu that's hidden by `display: none`, I get the menu hovered.

How a select option can hover a hidden object on click? This only happens on Chrome.

I tried to change select z-index to a higher.
Changed z-index for menu to -1 until parent ul get hovered, but no success, still get the issue

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vgrxt/) is a code

Try select the option test5:

```
ul.menu ul {
    display: none !important;
}

ul.menu li:hover>ul {
    display: block !important;
}

ul.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: 98%;
}

ul.menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 98%;
    top: -2px;
}

ul.menu, ul.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2px;
}

ul.menu li ul.links {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    border-color: #AAAAAA;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}

ul.menu ul.links li {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

ul.menu table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

ul.menu {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

ul.menu ul {
    width: 160.65px;
}

ul.menu li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

ul.menu a:active, ul.menu a:focus {
    outline-style: none;
}

ul.menu a, ul.menu li.dis a:hover, ul.menu li.sep a:hover {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-color: #6655ff;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

ul.menu ul.links a {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-color: #6655ff;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;
    font: normal 11px Verdana;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

ul.menu span {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul.menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

ul.menu ul li {
    float: none;
}

ul.menu ul a {
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.menu li.sep {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

ul.menu li.sep span {
    float: none;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    background-image: none;
}

ul.menu ul li.sep span {
    width: 80%;
    height: 3px;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
}

ul.menu li:hover>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px inset #CCCCCC;
    background: #E3E3E3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px inset #CCCCCC;
    background: #E3E3E3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}

ul.menu ul.links li:hover>a {
    background: #F8FBFE;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #BAE3FE;
}

ul.menu ul.links li a:hover {
    background: #F8FBFE;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #BAE3FE;
}

ul.menu li.dis a {
    color: #AAAAAA !important;
}

ul.menu img {
    border: none;
    float: left;
    _float: none;
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

ul.menu ul img {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

ul.menu img.over {
    display: none;
}

ul.menu li.dis a:hover img.over {
    display: none !important;
}

ul.menu li.dis a:hover img.def {
    display: inline !important;
}

ul.menu li:hover > a img.def {
    display: none;
}

ul.menu li:hover > a img.over {
    display: inline;
}

ul.menu a:hover img.over,ul.menu a:hover ul img.def,ul.menu a:hover a:hover ul img.def,ul.menu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul img.def,ul.menu a:hover a:hover img.over,ul.menu a:hover a:hover a:hover img.over,ul.menu a:hover a:hover a:hover a:hover img.over {
    display: inline;
}

ul.menu a:hover img.def,ul.menu a:hover ul img.over,ul.menu a:hover a:hover ul img.over,ul.menu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul img.over,ul.menu a:hover a:hover img.def,ul.menu a:hover a:hover a:hover img.def,ul.menu a:hover a:hover a:hover a:hover img.def {
    display: none;
}

ul.menu a:hover ul,ul.menu a:hover a:hover ul,ul.menu a:hover a:hover a:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

ul.menu a:hover ul ul,ul.menu a:hover a:hover ul ul {
    display: none;
}

ul.menu span {
    display: block;
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 0 2px 0;
}

ul.menu ul.links span {
    background-image: url(./images/arr_nav.gif);
}

ul.menu ul.links a:hover span,ul.menu table a:hover a:hover span,ul.menu table a:hover a:hover a:hover span {
    background-image: url(./images/arr_nav.gif);
}

/* DHTML WINDOW */
.dhtmlwindow {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
    #border-color: rgb(142, 153, 186);
    #border-color: rgba(142, 153, 186, 0.3);
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: paste your code here or fiddle it

Comment: There was a curly bracket missing at the end. Not sure if you missed it. I added it while updating the formatting.

Comment: cant replicate the issue here.

Comment: strange.. here in chrome i get the issue, when i select and click in test5 option, the menu pops out, my chrome version is 34.0.1847.131 m
this only happens in chrome. IE and Firefox works fine

Comment: @DanielEchizen: the "click test5 opens menue one" issues seems to occur by some invisible overlapping. If you enter some breaks <br/> between ul list and select list, it occurs on another number, e.g. test2. I will try to figure it out more clearly.

Comment: @dsuess yep! that's it! a overlapping. but the menu was supposed to be hidden. the test5 option was an example for the problem.

Comment: I still can not figure it out. Sorry. I up voted the question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on something I'm developing.  The fiddle seems to be working properly now - I can't duplicate your error.  Were changes made to fix the issue?  This only affects Chrome for Windows.  I've tested Safari, Chrome, FF on Mac and FF, Chrome, IE on Windows, as well as iOS and Android versions.

Comment: dint fix this yet. error still there ;/

Comment: I meet the same issue on Google Chrome 35.0.1916.153 but it seems no issue on Google Chrome 34.0.x; but it's hard to declare that if it's an issue of the version. OR can we find any work around solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in Chrome only, I could not replicate in FF.

Try adding these 2 lines they worked when I tried them out in your Fiddle.

```
ul.menu li {pointer-events: none;}
ul.menu:hover li {pointer-events: auto;}
```

Comment: Thanks that solved. what the function of pointer-events anyway?

Comment: It prevents mouse interaction with an object. You have to be very careful with it but Chrome has been getting some strange bugs lately and this sometimes helps.

Comment: It works for me; Re-tested on Chrome (v35), Firefox (v31) and IE11

Comment: thank you thank you thank you!!! I've spent 2 days trying to understand what the hell was happening ...